# Softlayer REST API for tagging machines

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Can someone please give me a Softlayer REST API for tagging machines that are already provisioned. I need to both for virtual machines and bare metal machines.

Thanks,
Kishore

Answer (score 0):

**Virtual Machine**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Tag/setTags
Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      "tag1,tag2",
      "GUEST",
      29756959
   ]
}

replace 29756959 with the ID of your virtual machine
```

**Bare metal**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Tag/setTags

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      "tag1,tag2",
      "HARDWARE",
      29756959
   ]
}

replace 29756959 with the ID of your bare metal
```